# Spring Data makes spring unable to find JAXRS's @Provider?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring + Jersey to build an API service .
Recently , I try to incorporate Spring Data to my server .
I haven't truly use any Repositories in my running code , just add one line in my app.xml :

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="destiny.web" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactoryApp" />
```

But ! I notice my API not working , complaining "**A message body writer for Java class xxx , and Java type class xxx , and MIME media type application/json was not found**"

If I remove the "jpa:repositories ..." line in my xml , everything works fine !
and , all provider classes are registered by spring :

```
{http://*:8080-1} Registering Spring bean, apiResultJsonWriter, of type destiny.web.api.ApiResultJsonWriter as a provider class
{http://*:8080-1} Registering Spring bean, webApi, of type destiny.web.api.WebApi as a root resource class
{http://*:8080-1} Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.8 06/24/2011 12:17 PM'
```

But , if I add "jpa:repositories..." line in my XML , only "root resources class" are registered :

```
{http://*:8080-1} CDI support is enabled
{http://*:8080-1} Using default applicationContext
{http://*:8080-1} Registering Spring bean, webApi, of type destiny.web.api.WebApi as a root resource class
{http://*:8080-1} Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.8 06/24/2011 12:17 PM'
```

All **JAXRS's @Provider**(s) are missing !

I don't know if it is Spring-Data's bug ? 
And how to solve it ?

environment :

```
spring-3.1
jersey-core-1.8.jar
jersey-server-1.8.jar
jersey-spring-1.8.jar

spring-data-jpa-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-commons-core-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar
```

server : `resin-4.0.25`

Related dependencies :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
  <exclusions> 
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId> 
    </exclusion> 
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

( I tried to add jersey-json , but still not working )

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the packages that contain classes annotated with `@Provider`

in Jersey 2 this is done via by calling the packages method in your `ResourceConfig` class.

I believe there is also a basepackages attribue you can put on the servlet. See here [Autodiscover JAX-RS resources with CXF in a Spring application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520821/autodiscover-jax-rs-resources-with-cxf-in-a-spring-application)