# setMaxResults for Spring-Data-JPA annotation?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to incorporate Spring-Data-JPA into my project.
One thing that confuses me is how do I achieve setMaxResults(n) by annotation ?

for example, my code:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User , Long>
{
  @Query(value="From User u where u.otherObj = ?1 ")
  public User findByOtherObj(OtherObj otherObj);
}
```

I only need to return `one (and only one)` User from otherObj, but I cannot find a way to annotate the maxResults. Can somebody give me a hint ?

(mysql complains :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@5add5415: select user0_.id as id100_, user0_.created as created100_ from User user0_ where user0_.id=2 limit ** NOT SPECIFIED **
WARN  util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 07001
ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter - No value specified for parameter 2
```

)

I found a link : https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-147,
I tried but failed. It seems not possible now?
Why is such an important feature not built into Spring-Data?

If I implement this feature manually:

```
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository
```

I have to implement tons of predefined methods in `CrudRepository`, this would be terrible.

environments : spring-3.1 , spring-data-jpa-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar , spring-data-commons-core-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar

Answer (score 211):

### As of Spring Data JPA 1.7.0 (Evans release train).

You can use the newly introduced `Top` and `First` keywords that allow you to define query methods like this:

```
findTop10ByLastnameOrderByFirstnameAsc(String lastname);
```

Spring Data will automatically limit the results to the number you defined (defaulting to 1 if omitted). Note that the ordering of the results becomes relevant here (either through an `OrderBy` clause as seen in the example or by handing a `Sort` parameter into the method). Read more on that in the blog post covering [new features of the Spring Data Evans release train](https://spring.io/blog/2014/10/15/whats-new-in-spring-data-evans#user-content-statically-limiting-results) or in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result).

### For previous versions

To retrieve only slices of data, Spring Data uses the pagination abstraction which comes with a `Pageable` interface on the requesting side as well as a `Page` abstraction on the result side of things. So you could start with

```
public interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {

  List<User> findByUsername(String username, Pageable pageable);
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Pageable topTen = new PageRequest(0, 10);
List<User> result = repository.findByUsername("Matthews", topTen);
```

If you need to know the context of the result (which page is it actually? is it the first one? how many are there in total?), use `Page` as return type:

```
public interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {

  Page<User> findByUsername(String username, Pageable pageable);
}
```

The client code can then do something like this:

```
Pageable topTen = new PageRequest(0, 10);
Page<User> result = repository.findByUsername("Matthews", topTen);
Assert.assertThat(result.isFirstPage(), is(true));
```

Not that we will trigger a count projection of the actual query to be executed in case you use `Page` as return type as we need to find out how many elements there are in total to calculate the metadata. Beyond that, be sure you actually equip the `PageRequest` with sorting information to get stable results. Otherwise you might trigger the query twice and get different results even without the data having changed underneath.

Comment: Thanks , but I still hope for an 'annotation based' solution. Because 'Page / Pageable' are too overkill in this case. And client has to create a Pageable/Page to retrieve 'one and only one' result... It's very un-friendly to use.  And it seems you are in charge of Spring-Data , I hope you can further look into this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276461/spring-data-makes-spring-unable-to-find-jaxrss-provider . Can you confirm if it is Spring-Data's bug ?

Comment: @chrismarx - It just works :). We can still call the necessary methods on the `Query` instance. For the count query, we us provider specific API to extract the JPQL query from the source query and then apply the count projection on it.

Comment: + this works, thanks  but an annotation based solution would be better in newer versions

Comment: a count query is fired here which is totally unnecessary if we want a limited query.

Comment: It's not if you use `List` as the return type of the method.

Comment: I think, `Top` and `First` keywords are not applicable to methods that use `@Query` annotation? Only those, which use method-name-based query generation?

Comment: I also found it doesn't work with @Query annotation. Is there any way to get the latest for Query ?

Comment: Just fyi. PageRequest is still very relevant and not limited to previous versions. Infact, the usage of PageRequest is far more than findTopXXX. 

In Spring 5, the syntax has changed to `PageRequest.of(0, 10)`

Answer (score 120):

If you are using Java 8 and Spring Data 1.7.0, you can use default methods if you want to combine a `@Query` annotation with setting maximum results:

```
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User,Long> {
  @Query("from User u where ...")
  List<User> findAllUsersWhereFoo(@Param("foo") Foo foo, Pageable pageable);

  default List<User> findTop10UsersWhereFoo(Foo foo) {
    return findAllUsersWhereFoo(foo, new PageRequest(0,10));
  }

}
```

Comment: potentially useful for a single result `Stream<User> ... {...} default Optional<User> ... { ...findAny() }`

Answer (score 31):

There is a way you can provide the equivalent of "a setMaxResults(n) by annotation" like in the following:

```
public interface ISomething extends JpaRepository<XYZ, Long>
{
    @Query("FROM XYZ a WHERE a.eventDateTime < :before ORDER BY a.eventDateTime DESC")
    List<XYZ> findXYZRecords(@Param("before") Date before, Pageable pageable);
}
```

This should do the trick, when a pageable is sent as parameter.
For instance to fetch the first 10 records you need to set pageable to this value:

```
new PageRequest(0, 10)
```

Comment: If you are using Pagable then its return Page<XYZ> not List<XYZ>

Comment: @Arundev wrong - `List` works perfectly (and avoids an unnecessary `count` query as already mentioned in [a previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314078/setmaxresults-for-spring-data-jpa-annotation#comment-40486876))

Answer (score 28):

## [Use Spring Data Evans  (1.7.0 RELEASE)](https://spring.io/blog/2014/10/15/whats-new-in-spring-data-evans#comment-1642206064)

the new release of Spring Data JPA with another list of modules together called [Evans](https://spring.io/blog/2014/09/09/spring-data-release-train-evans-goes-ga) has the feature of using keywords `Top20` and `First` to limit the query result,

so you could now write

> ```
> List<User> findTop20ByLastname(String lastname, Sort sort);
> ```

or

> ```
> List<User> findTop20ByLastnameOrderByIdDesc(String lastname);
> ```

or for a single result

> ```
> List<User> findFirstByLastnameOrderByIdDesc(String lastname);
> ```

Comment: Optional<User> findFirstByLastnameOrderByIdDesc(String lastname);

Comment: After getting top20 results, How would I get the next 20 results when I go to next page on the website using pagination?

Comment: @kittu, that of course is another question but you need to pass a `Pageable` object. check out spring documentation

Comment: why they made the method return a damn List if it's specified FIRST ??

Comment: Better to write return type of last method (`findFirstByLastnameOrderByIdDesc`) as `Optional<User>` or even just `User`

Answer (score 15):

Best choice for me is native query:

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM users WHERE other_obj = ?1 LIMIT 1", nativeQuery = true)
User findByOhterObj(OtherObj otherObj);
```

Comment: Not sure if limit is supported in Hibernate: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=939314

Comment: Breaks the whole concept! Better use EntityManager instead!

Comment: @Code.IT I propagate KISS concept.
Aside from that  JPA `nativeQuery`  annotation parameter added not for ignoring.

Comment: @GKislin than you have to rename you method like findLimitOneByOtherObj. Also you have forgotten to add an OrderBy which leads to wrong result if the other_obj is not unique. Otherwise a where statement on a unique column should be enough without a limit one

Comment: LIMIT keyword is not hibernate but postgres/mysql

Comment: Nice one, works for me, replaced "?1" with ":param."

Answer (score 11):

`new PageRequest(0,10)` doesn't work in newer Spring versions (I am using `2.2.1.RELEASE`). Basically, the constructor got an additional parameter as `Sort` type. Moreover, the constructor is `protected` so you have to either use one of its child classes or call its `of` static method:

```
PageRequest.of(0, 10, Sort.sort(User.class).by(User::getFirstName).ascending()))
```

You can also omit the use of `Sort` parameter and implicitly user the default sort  (sort by pk, etc.):

```
PageRequest.of(0, 10)
```

Your function declaration should be something like this:

```
List<User> findByUsername(String username, Pageable pageable)
```

and the function will be:

```
userRepository.findByUsername("Abbas", PageRequest.of(0,10, Sort.sort(User.class).by(User::getLastName).ascending());
```

Answer (score 6):

It's also posible using @QueryHints. Example bellow uses org.eclipse.persistence.config.QueryHints#JDBC_MAX_ROWS

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE .....")
@QueryHints(@QueryHint(name = JDBC_MAX_ROWS, value = "1"))
Voter findUser();
```

Comment: I've test this code but it's not working. No exception, but no proper result neighter. Also the documentation is very thin about QueryHints. See below.  
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-hints

Comment: IIRC, there are no *guarantees* that a query hint will be followed. It's just a way to pass "friendly recommendations" to the implementation.

Comment: I try it with `@QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.annotations.FETCH_SIZE, value = "1")})` in Hibernate, but alias:( doesn't work

Comment: org.hibernate.annotations.FETCH_SIZE its fetch size,its not limit, not max results. Hiber cant

Answer (score 5):

If your class `@Repository` extends `JpaRepository` you can use the example below.

```
int limited = 100;
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0,limited);
Page<Transaction> transactionsPage = transactionRepository.findAll(specification, pageable);
return transactionsPage.getContent();
```

getContent return a `List<Transaction>`.

Comment: what if I have 2 where conditions in query like, transactionRepository.findByFirstNameAndLastName(firstname, lastname) ? will it work ? I am getting this exception org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property create found for type Board.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe after 12 years. Sping-Data-JPA still has no actual solution.
I ended up writing a custom Repository implementation.

```java
public class CustomJpaRepository <Entity, Id> extends JpaRepositoryImplementation<Entity, Id> {
  Optional<Entity> findFirst(String query, Map<String, Object> parameters, String entityGraph);
}

public class CustomExtendedJpaRepository<E, I> extends SimpleJpaRepository<E, I> implements ExtendedJpaRepository<E, I>{

    private final EntityManager entityManager;
    private final Class<E> domainClass;

    public CustomExtendedJpaRepository(JpaEntityInformation<E, I> entityInformation, EntityManager em) {
        super(entityInformation, em);
        this.entityManager = em;
        this.domainClass = entityInformation.getJavaType();
    }

    public CustomExtendedJpaRepository(Class<E> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
        super(domainClass, em);
        this.entityManager = em;
        this.domainClass = domainClass;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Optional<E> findFirst(String query, Map<String, Object> parameters, String entityGraph) {
        var tq = entityManager.createQuery(query, domainClass);
        for (var p : parameters.entrySet()) {
            tq.setParameter(p.getKey(), p.getValue());
        }
        if (entityGraph != null) {
            tq.setHint(AvailableHints.HINT_SPEC_FETCH_GRAPH, entityManager.getEntityGraph(entityGraph));
        }
        tq.setMaxResults(1);
        return Optional.ofNullable(tq.getSingleResult());
    }
}
```

To enable custom implementation

```java
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "your.company.persistence",
        repositoryBaseClass = CustomExtendedJpaRepository.class
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0,1);
Page<Transaction> transactionsPage = transactionRepository.findAll(specification, pageable);
return transactionsPage.getContent();
```