# How to return a single result from Spring-Data-JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to get a single result from a Spring Data query.  I'm looking to return the greatest ID from a user table.  I was hoping it would be straightforward, but I'm a little lost.

So far, based on [this related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9315989/827480), I've come to the conclusion that I need to use a `Specification` to define my query and `Page`d results, specifying the number of results I want to retrieve. Unfortunately, I'm getting a `HibernateJdbcException` data access exception.

My `Specification`/`Predicate` is supposed to be fairly simple and reflect: `from User order by id`:

```
Page<User> result =userRepository.findAll(new Specification<User>() {
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<User> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        query.orderBy(cb.desc(root.get("id")));
        return query.getRestriction();
    }
}, new PageRequest(0, 10));

MatcherAssert.assertThat(result.isFirstPage(), is(true));
User u = result.getContent().get(0);
```

Exception Thrown:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [n/a]; SQL state [90016]; error code [90016]; could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:651)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:106)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
    ...
    ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.executeCountQuery(QueryUtils.java:406)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.readPage(SimpleJpaRepository.java:433)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:332)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:358)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "USER1_.ID" must be in the GROUP BY list; SQL statement:
/* select count(generatedAlias0) from User as generatedAlias0, User as generatedAlias1 where 1=1 order by generatedAlias1.id desc */ select count(user0_.id) as col_0_0_ from user user0_ cross join user user1_ where 1=1 order by user1_.id desc [90016-173]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:331)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:171)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:148)
    at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.updateAggregate(ExpressionColumn.java:166)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryGroup(Select.java:344)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryWithoutCache(Select.java:620)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:314)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:284)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:36)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:91)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:195)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
    ... 78 more
```

I'm a little lost by the Hibernate error - it's asking for a `group` clause.  I presume it has something to do with the way I've created the Predicate, but I am not sure how to create a simple predicate like this.

**EDIT**

As suggested by @OliverGierke, I tried to remove the `root = query.from(User.class)` but the hibernate still throws the same error (I enabled full hibernate query tracing).  Strangely, however, this time, there is no `GROUP BY` in the generated SQL so I'm even more confused than before.

```
2014-03-18 11:59:44,475 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    /* select
        count(generatedAlias0) 
    from
        User as generatedAlias0 
    order by
        generatedAlias0.id desc */ select
            count(user0_.id) as col_0_0_ 
        from
            user user0_ 
        order by
            user0_.id desc
Hibernate: 
    /* select
        count(generatedAlias0) 
    from
        User as generatedAlias0 
    order by
        generatedAlias0.id desc */ select
            count(user0_.id) as col_0_0_ 
        from
            user user0_ 
        order by
            user0_.id desc
2014-03-18 11:59:44,513 [main] WARN  hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 90016, SQLState: 90016
2014-03-18 11:59:44,513 [main] ERROR hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Column "USER0_.ID" must be in the GROUP BY list; SQL statement:
/* select count(generatedAlias0) from User as generatedAlias0 order by generatedAlias0.id desc */ select count(user0_.id) as col_0_0_ from user user0_ order by user0_.id desc [90016-173]
```

Comment: This will solve your problem without the need for a specification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314078

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're not using the `root` getting handed into the `Specification` instance to invoke the `.get(…)` method on. That fails the instance to register `id` being used and thus transparently adding it to the result set.

Simply removing `root = query.from(User.class);` should do the trick.

What puzzles me though is that you mention you're intending to build a "find by id" query. What you're actually building is a "find all ordered by id". If it's really the former you want to get, there's a predefined `findOne(…)` method on `CrudRepository` you can use.

Given the comments below it seems what you're actually trying to achieve is finding a single user with the smallest id. This can also be achieved by simply extending `PagingAndSortingRepository` and then use client code like this:

```
interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> { … }

Page<User> users = repository.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 1, Direction.ASC, "id"));
User user = users.getContent.get(0);
```

This will limit the result to the first page by a page size of 1 with ascending ordering by id.

Comment: Removing `root = ...` from the predicate did not help.  I've edited my question to reflect the changes when I remove `root = ...` from the predicate.   I'm actually trying to build a "find greatest id" query.  I'm only interested in the greatest `id`.  The `findOne(...)` in the `CrudRepository` failed (understandably) when there was more than 1 result filtered by the predicate.  To be honest, I'm not entirely sure what the best way to do this is; I'm new to SpringData and still trying to learn how to use it properly.

Comment: Your code sample above still contains the invalid line. Is that by intention? I'll update my answer with a suggested workaround.

Comment: Thanks; I'll try your suggestion.  I had not edited the original code in my post; I'll fix that now.  Is there a reason why the other method does not work?  Is that a bug in Spring Data?

Comment: You just build an invalid SQL statement / Criteria query… :)

Comment: :) Any idea what makes it an invalid criteria?

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure why you are fetching a collection to get a single result. Correct me if I'm wrong but the solution to your problem, as I interpreted it, is very easy to solve using `@Query`. Add the following to your repository interface.

```
@Query("SELECT max(t.id) FROM #{#entityName} t")
Integer getMaxId();
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this without `@Query` and modifying my repository interface. It's actually a method I only need in a unit test, and consequently, I'm trying to use use the Specification/Predicate to retrieve the same information.  Do you know of a way I can do this without modifying the repo interface?

Comment: I don't have any experience using them. Never needed them. I cannot recommend you a different solution. Sorry.