# CrudRepository: Return one result, ordered by a column

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-data

Is there a way for a CrudRepository interface to sort a table with multiple rows and simply return the first row, e.g. sort by a timestamp to return only the latest row?

```
public interface ImportReceiptRepository extends CrudRepository<ImportReceipt, Long>
{
    ImportReceipt getOneByImportTypeOrderByTimestampDesc(String importType);
    ImportReceipt findOneByImportTypeOrderByTimestampDesc(String importType);
}
```

Both findOneBy... and getOneBy... throw:

```
org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: result returns more than one elements; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:395)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:216)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:105)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy109.findOneByImportTypeOrderByTimestampDesc(Unknown Source)
at edu.ucdavis.dss.dw.services.DefaultImportReceiptService.getLatestOneByImportType(DefaultImportReceiptService.java:26)
...
```

Or, putting it another way, what's the CrudRepository equivalent of:

```
SELECT * FROM ImportReceipts ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0,1;
```

Comment: Not sure it's a duplicate: that answer and the one it is in turn a duplicate of refer to having JPA Query objects which is not the case with CrudRepository.

Comment: Looks like Bludream's answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314078/setmaxresults-for-spring-data-jpa-annotation is what I'm looking for. The syntax is "findFirst" or "findTop10" though it still returns a list. Thanks for the help holmis83, your link set me on the right path.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know it was so different from "standard" JPA. Well, I learned something new.

Answer (score 12):

Bludream's answer from [setMaxResults for Spring-Data-JPA annotation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314078/)… has the answer.

The syntax is "findFirst" or "findTop10" though it still returns a list.

```
List<ImportReceipt> findFirstByImportTypeOrderByTimestampDesc(String importType);
```

I suppose List will always be of size() 0 or 1.

Comment: For me this method returns a list with size equal to all rows that have the importType