# Fetching only first/last element using Spring Data JPA and @Query annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

**EDIT:** Solutions to this problem are provided in the second and fourth answer regarding this question [setMaxResults for Spring-Data-JPA annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314078/setmaxresults-for-spring-data-jpa-annotation)

**Goal:** Fetch the largest/smallest element by property z using a Spring Data JPA repository and the Spring Query annotation.

What I have so far

```
@Query("SELECT xelement FROM x xelement ORDER BY xelement.z")
public List<X> findFirstElement();
```

**Problem:** This query fetches all elements (which is not really effective). If I would use the EntityManager direcly, I could set the number of results using

```
entityManager.setMaxResults(1)
```

to only get the first element.

**Question:** How do I specify the maximum number of results using the **@Query** annotation?

**Idea:** Is using a PageRequest of size 0 the way to go?

**Constraints:** I am aware of the "FindFirstBy...." query feature but I want/have to use the `@Query` annotation.

Comment: Why does your method return `List<X>` when it is only expected to return a single element?  If the query is really that simple, you can avoid using `@Query` and simply have `findFirstOrderByZ()`.  Otherwise, you will have to use the `LIMIT` keyword to restrict the number of records returned `SELECT x FROM xelement x ORDER BY x.z LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @manish: 1. regarding the List<X>, this was just to be flexible enough in case I would switch an arbitrary number of items, but yes, in principle you are correct, returning a list is overkill in this case. 2. Regarding the "findFirst.." --> see constraints. 3. Are you sure the limit keyword is available in JPQL? I guess I have to check it .... I also found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314078/setmaxresults-for-spring-data-jpa-annotation which pretty much solves the problem.

Comment: Found this to be covered by the second and fourth answer in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314078/setmaxresults-for-spring-data-jpa-annotation][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314078/setmaxresults-for-spring-data-jpa-annotation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setMaxResults for Spring-Data-JPA annotation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314078/setmaxresults-for-spring-data-jpa-annotation)

Comment: Please don't refer to answers by their order in the list.  *This order changes*.  Please link directly to the answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045439/technical-differences-between-spring-data-jpas-findfirst-and-findtop

Answer (score 20):

You can use the limit property of sql just by adding nativeQuery to @Query annotation. However, there is another and a better way of doing this. Pageable class in your repository method will solve your problem without touching your @Query annotation:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT xelement FROM x xelement ORDER BY xelement.z")
List<X> findFirstElement(Pageable limit);
```

To set the limit and offset, use should call this repository method as follows:

```
List<X> xValues = xRepository.findFirstElement(new PageRequest(0, 1));
```

Here 1 corresponds to the limit which you want.

**UPDATE (SPRING DATA 2.0)**

Use **PageRequest.of(0, 1)** instead of **new PageRequest(0, 1)**

Comment: As of spring-data 2.0 it's `PagaRequest.of(0, 1)` instead of `new PageRequest(0, 1)`.

Comment: The parameter in the function should be `findFirstElement(PageRequest limit)` and not `Pageable`, right? At least for me it doesn't work with Pageable.

Answer (score 9):

The closest JPA query syntax I can think for your use case is `findFirstByZIsNotNullOrderByZAsc`. This should eliminate the need to write custom native query.

Answer (score -2):

Try to do this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT xelement FROM x xelement ORDER BY xelement.z  LIMIT 1",
       nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: It just does not work. U are mixing between native query with JPQL syntax.