# Technical differences between Spring Data JPA's findFirst and findTop

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I recently started working with Spring data jpa.

It would be highly appreciable if somebody could throw some light on the ***technical differences*** between **Spring Data JPA's** `findFirst` and `findTop`.

Differences, usages.

Thanks

Answer (score 108, accepted):

From [Spring Data JPA - Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result),

### Limiting query results

The results of query methods can be limited via the keywords `first` or `top`, which can be used interchangeably. An optional numeric value can be appended to `top/first` to specify the maximum result size to be returned. If the number is left out, a result size of 1 is assumed.

### Limiting the result size of a query with Top and First

```
User findFirstByOrderByLastnameAsc();

User findTopByOrderByAgeDesc();

Page<User> queryFirst10ByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);

Slice<User> findTop3ByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);

List<User> findFirst10ByLastname(String lastname, Sort sort);

List<User> findTop10ByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);
```

The limiting expressions also support the `Distinct` keyword. Also, for the queries limiting the result set to one instance, wrapping the result into an Optional is supported.

Comment: hi, i am trying to user this method User findTopByOrderByAgeDesc(); but i am getting Incorrect syntax near 'limit' can you please tell me what is the root cause

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: If `first` and `top` can be used interchangeably, why we need both?@SkyWalker

Comment: @logbasex The results of query methods can be limited by using the `first` or `top` keywords, which can be used **interchangeably**.

Comment: @suri findTopOrderByAgeDesc should be the correct way to do it

Comment: will it give null if no record exists? just for confirmation.

Comment: @PSatishPatro I would use `Optional<User>` as return value, if you are not sure, if an entry exists

Comment: @StefanHaberl, but when you want Page or List you can't use Optional. Sorry, my question was not clear. But, now I know Page, List all will give empty result instead of null