# How do you limit the fetch query size in Hibernate JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am getting this error [com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759418/com-mysql-jdbc-packettoobigexception) and tracing through the code, it appears that it occurs on the following scenario (but only on tests)

```java
public interface Students extends JpaRepository<Student, Integer> {

    @EntityGraph("Student.withProgramAndSchedule")
    @Query("from Student s")
    Iterable<Student> findAllWithProgramAndSchedule();
}
```

```java
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "Student.withProgramAndSchedule",
    attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode("programEnrollments"),
        @NamedAttributeNode("schedules")
    }
)
public class Student implements Serializable {
...
}
```

Only during DataJpaTest it appears it does not clean up the Entity Manager context even when I had cleared the entity manager

```
@After
public void clearEntityManager() {
    entityManager.clear();
}
```

Since this is with anonymized real data, it has thousands of records and what happens is it creates a query that looks like

```sql
select ... from ... where studentSchedule_0.id in (?, ?, ... thousands of ? later, ... ?)
```

Then it blows the 1MB packet limit.

So my question is (because I can't find it in the references) is it possible to limit the query size when it does the fetch with the IDs?

Comment: Clearing the entity manager isn't the same as removing something from the database.

Comment: I don't want it removed from the database, the clearing was supposed to detach the objects from the entity manager.

Comment: That obviously won't work in reducing the amount of selects. You are using a fetch graph which needs to fetch additional information. So the query will be issued anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I am not in a place that let's me code up to confirm what I think will work.

Using findFirst as below:

findFirstWithProgramAndSchedule()  // gets one

Or to limit to the first 10

findFirst10WithProgramAndSchedule()

I am trying to be helpful, even though I can't code it up today.  Thus, I waited to see if others had the answer, but I believe this will work per the references.

Reference:

[Technical differences between Spring Data JPA's findFirst and findTop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045439/technical-differences-between-spring-data-jpas-findfirst-and-findtop)

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result

Comment: Thanks, but I am not trying to limit the query result.  I am trying to limit the query size.  The query is generated by Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jpa pagination to limit query result :

```
Iterable<Student> findAllWithProgramAndSchedule(Pageable pageable);
```

and for test:

```
Pageable page= PageRequest.of(1, 5);
```

Comment: again, I am not trying to limit the result set.  I am trying to limit the size of the query that is sent to get the associated entity graph.