# jpa order records descending and select first record

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I have a spring boot app connected to oracle DB.
I am trying to order a list of records and select the top most record.

I wrote a JPA query as below but it fails.

```
@Query("SELECT id FROM UploadedFile uploadedFile "
    + "WHERE uploadedFile.p_file_type = 'branch' "
    + "and p_file_status='Processed' "
    + "and p_is_file_process_with_error = 0 "
    + "order by c_created_date desc "
    + "FETCH FIRST 1 rows only ")
public String findLatestBranchCodeFile();
```

The error received was

> creating bean with name 'uploadedFileRepo': Invocation of init method
> failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> Validation failed for query for method public abstract
> java.lang.String
> com.rhb.pintas.repo.UploadedFileRepo.findLatestBranchCodeFile()!
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:
> FETCH near line 1, column 204 [SELECT id FROM
> com.rhb.pintas.entities.UploadedFile uploadedFile WHERE
> uploadedFile.p_file_type = 'branch' and p_file_status='Processed' and
> p_is_file_process_with_error = 0 order by c_created_date desc FETCH
> FIRST 1 rows only ] -> [Help 1]

The issue seems to be with fetch,not sure whats wrong.

Comment: Did you try using `LIMIT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are mixing HQL and native query dialects:

If this will be a naviveQuery (like most of the columns would mention), then **replace the entity name with table name** and **add nativeQuery option**. And because You are using only a single table, You can skip the alias name:

```
 @Query("SELECT id FROM uploaded_file "
        + "WHERE p_file_type = 'branch' and p_file_status='Processed' and "
        + "p_is_file_process_with_error = 0 "
        + "order by c_created_date desc "
        + "FETCH FIRST 1 rows only ", nativeQuery = true)
    public String findLatestBranchCodeFile();
```

If You want to keep it as a HQL, then replace all column names with entity property names, like p_file_type > fileType (I guess column names). Secondly You will need to pass a Pageable parameter, to replace Your 'Fetch first' statement.

You can find more materials here:

- [Bealdung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query)
- [NativeQ](https://thorben-janssen.com/native-queries-with-spring-data-jpa/)
- [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948795/is-it-possible-to-use-raw-sql-within-a-spring-repository)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to execute SQL query, in this case you need to add `nativeQuery=true` attribute to `@Query` annotation

---

UPD.

got confused because `FETCH FIRST` - is a SQL syntax, for JPA way please check [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459618/fetching-only-first-last-element-using-spring-data-jpa-and-query-annotation) - it is possible to return list with at most one element.

Comment: thanks.......if i was to do it 100% jpa query way, wat will my query be?

Comment: That is a JPA query.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can try passing pagable to limit result set size and unlimit your query:

```
public String findLatestBranchCodeFile(Pageable pageable); // pass new PageRequest(0,1)
```