# Spring IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException for query returning Long value? Java

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I have added a new query method to an existing JPA repository which retrieves an id as type `Long` from an OrderItem entity as so:

```
    @Transactional("order_item")
public interface OrderItemRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<OrderItem, Integer> {

    ...other queries

    /**
     * Retrieves the latest modification Id of order item entity
     *
     * @param orderItemId id
     * @return modificationId | null if order item is not a print product
     */
    @Query("select pri.modificationId from OrderItem as oi"
            + " join oi.physicalItems as phys"
            + " join phys.printItem as pri"
            + " where oi.id = :orderItemId"
            + " order by pri.modificationId desc")
    Long findLatestmodificationIdForOrderItem(@Param("orderItemId") Integer orderItemId);

}
```

The query mostly works but sometimes it breaks with this error in the log:

> org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: result returns more than one elements; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements
>
> at 
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy993.findLatestModificationIdForOrderItem(Unknown Source)

After consulting this SO question: [setMaxResults for Spring-Data-JPA annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314078/setmaxresults-for-spring-data-jpa-annotation)

That solution was to change the methods return type to a List, but htis will break my contract and require refactor in a lot of places.

How can I limit the query to always return one value and not break?

Thanks

Comment: I'd leave the query and the contract.  Change the implementation of the interface to return a List ordered by time and return the latest one (first or last in the List).

Answer (score 2):

Please Try Example :

```
@Transactional("order_item")
public interface OrderItemRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<OrderItem, Integer> {

@Query("select pri.modificationId from OrderItem as oi"
        + " join oi.physicalItems as phys"
        + " join phys.printItem as pri"
        + " where oi.id = :orderItemId"
        + " order by pri.modificationId desc")
List<Long> findLatestmodificationIdForOrderItemQuery(@Param("orderItemId") Integer orderItemId);

  default Long findLatestmodificationIdForOrderItem(Integer orderItemId) {
        List<Long> result = this.findLatestmodificationIdForOrderItemQuery(orderItemId);
        return result.get(0);
  }
}
```