# How to limit the result with @Query?

Tags: spring-data

Im tried to use the `LIMIT` key word in my `@Query` annotated query but it doesn't seem to work as its not supported.

Is there any change to deliver only one record from a `SELECT` query?

I ve seen it would work with Hibernate CriteriaBuilder or Query objectsif used as they give the possibility to set a max size or limit but haven't seen any solution yet which would work with the `@Query` annotation.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314078/setmaxresults-for-spring-data-jpa-annotation

Comment: Thanks guys. Deciced to go the route with Pageble as i want to implement also a REST api later. Thx!