# Spring Data: limit result for custom query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

In my Spring Data repository I (have to) use custom queries using the `@Query` annotation. I know I can limit the number of results in a named query like that

`Iterable<Person> findFirst5OrderByLastName()`

or that it is possible to limit the number of results by passing a pageable like that

`Iterable<Person> findByLastName(String lastName, Pageable pageable)`

But is it possible to achieve the same when using a custom `@Query` annotation?

TIA

**EDIT**

as I see my question is a little confusing, some clearification:
What I want is to limit the number of the results I get, when using a custom query, so that I neither

1) need to specify the result-size through a pageable

2) need to use a named query to specify the result-size

In fact I want the limitation of the number of results to be completely transparent when invoking method (hence not passing a `Pageable`) and to not rely on the naming-scheme of Spring Data (as the meaning/function of the method is best conveyed through a custom name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setMaxResults for Spring-Data-JPA annotation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314078/setmaxresults-for-spring-data-jpa-annotation)

Comment: I added some clearification on why I think it is not a duplicate/is not answered there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons") 
public class Person {
    //...
}

@Query(value = "select * from persons limit 50", nativeQuery = true)
List<Person> getFirst50();
```

Don't forget to check  whether your SQL server supports the [limit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use @Query to order a result, it is an JPQL query e.g.

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u ORDER BY u.name ASC")
```

Further sorting can be done be either providing a PageRequest or using Sort directly.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.sorting

Comment: Question is related to How to Limit Query Result Size and not about SORT

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to add "**By**" but without parameter, it would work:

```
List<Person> findTop100By();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can try this

```
@Query("...")
List<YourDTO>getData(Pageable pageable)
```

In your serviceImpl

```
    List<YourDTO> getData(){
    int limit=10;
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, limit);
    return this.repo.getData(pageable);
}
```

You should avoid nativeQuery

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend PagingAndSortingRepository

and add method

```
Page<Person> listAllByPage(Pageable pageable)
```

See [the example](http://ankushs92.github.io/tutorial/2016/05/03/pagination-with-spring-boot.html)