# Spring Data JPA: get first record using @Query annotation on query method

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

My query method returns list of entities:

```
@Query("select u from ProfileDMO p inner join p.userPrincipal u where p.id=:profileId")
    List<UserPrincipalDMO> findUserPrincipalByProfileId(@Param("profileId") long profileId);
```

And I need only first result. Currently, I am using `List.get(int index)` to get first element.

Does anyone know how should I update my query method to return only first result?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35265491/5020294

Comment: @AndriySlobodyanyk, thanks for response. That solution works for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

If you can't use a derived query where Spring Data JPA derives the query from the method name you can use a `Pageable` parameter to limit the results and a second method with a default implementation to hide the parameter and unwrap the result:

```
@Query("select u from ProfileDMO p inner join p.userPrincipal u where p.id=:profileId")
List<UserPrincipalDMO> internalFindUserPrincipalByProfileId(@Param("profileId") long profileId, Pageable page);

default UserPrincipalDMO findUserPrincipalByProfileId(long profileId){
    return internalFindUserPrincipalByProfileId(
        profileId, 
        PageRequest.of(0,1)
    ).get(0);
};
```

Of course, that leaves the internal implementation in your API, if you don't like that you always can fall back to a custom implementation.

**Original answer:**

You should be able to use query derivation, i.e. remove the `@Query` annotation and change your method to:

```
UserPrincipalDMO findFirstByUserPrincipalProfileId(@Param("profileId") long profileId);
```

If you don't like the name you can use a default method with your preferred name and delegate to the one I proposed.

If you don't want the method name at all in your interface you can provide a custom implementation.

Comment: thanks for your response. I couldn't use here query generation from method name approach, as `UserPrincipalDMO` entity doesn't have relation with `ProfileDMO` entity.

Comment: oh, I see the relation is the other way round. That leaves you with a custom implementation.

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution that is easier to implement.

Comment: should be `PageRequest.of(0, 1)`