# Add maximum size limit and direction to findAllByTypeAndCreatedAtAfter() mongodb method

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, java-8

Is it possible to formulate a query method like the one below that returns a List `1)of max size n`,

containing Appliance objects that were `2) createdAfter a specific time (Instant) at DESC order`,

and `3) they are of a specific TypeEnum`. I have pinned down the `1st` and `2nd` requirement but

I have not found out how to add the `max size` and `direction`restrictions.

```
<T extends Appliance> List<T> findAllByTypeAndCreatedAtAfter(ApplianceTypeEnum applianceTypeEnum);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setMaxResults for Spring-Data-JPA annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314078/setmaxresults-for-spring-data-jpa-annotation)

Comment: Thank you, but not exactly. I want to also be able to define the direction in the list, based on the createdAt attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<T extends Appliance> List<T> findFirst3ByTypeAndCreatedAtAfterDesc(ApplianceTypeEnum applianceTypeEnum);
```

You can read more about Spring Derived Queries [HERE](https://attacomsian.com/blog/derived-query-methods-spring-data-jpa)

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to make the max size - in this case three - dynamic?

Comment: As I know You can pass sorting order as parameter, but I'm not sure in case of max size. In this case I always use native queries.