# Select the top row in JPQL without using native query option

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

How is it possible to select the first row at the top of the selection without using native query option in JPQL/JPA?

```
@Query("select e from FOO e order by e.orderNumber desc")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314078/setmaxresults-for-spring-data-jpa-annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *might* be able to use a max subquery here to restrict to the "first" row:

```
select e from FOO e where orderNumber = (select max(f.orderNumber) from FOO f);
```

This would be logically correct if `orderNumber` would always be guaranteed to be unique, in which case there would only be one max value.